# Finite type + integral = finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A \subseteq B$ be rings (comm. with unity).

I am struggling to see why the following equivalence holds for $B$ interpreted as a $A$-Algebra:

$A \rightarrow B$ is of finite type and $A\subseteq B$ is integral $\Leftrightarrow$ $A \rightarrow B$ is finite.

It should be possible to conclude this by using $b \in B$ integral over $A \Leftrightarrow$ $A[b]$ finitely generated as an $A$-module and one or two other elementary statements.

Comment: You are on the right track. Have you tried the case $B=A[b,c]$?

Comment: Following the hint above, you can proceed via induction.

Comment: Jep, I also understand the induction part. But how to conclude the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the hints in the comments, note that

$B = A[b_1, ..., b_n]$ for certain $b_i \in B$ since $A\rightarrow B$ is of finite type.

Now the statement follows via induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$, $B$ be rings, let $B$ be an $A$-algebra with a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$.

"finite type + integral = finite" (in terms of $f$)

is equivalent to

"$B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra + $B$ is integral over $f(A)$ = $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module" (in terms of $B$)

Let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. Then $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra, by the definition.

For any $x\in B$,  $f(A)[x]$ is contained in $B$ implies that $x$ is integral over $f(A)$, (by Prop 5.1 in Atiyah's book)

so the claim follows.

Conversely, let $B$ be a finitely generated $A$-algebra + integral over $f(A)$.

Then, by the def, there exists a surjective $A$-algebra homomorphism $g:A[t_1,\cdots,t_n]\to B$.

Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in B$ be the images of indeterminants $t_1,\cdots, t_n$ under $g$.

Since the $x_i$ are integral over $f(A)$,

$f(A)[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is finitely generated as a $f(A)$-module, by Cor 5.2., so as an $A$-module.

Since $g$ is surjective, $B=f(A)[x_1,\cdots,x_n].$