# How to show $R$ is finitely generated as $R^G$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a field. Let $R$ be a $K$-algebra of finite type with a $G$-action leaving $K$ fixed. Define $R^G:=\{r\in R | gx=x \ \forall x\in G\}$. Show that $R$ is finitely generated as $R^G$-module.

**Attempt**. First of all, we know that $R$ is integral over $R^G$.

1. Since $R$ is a $K$-algebra with a $G$-action leaving $K$ fixed, there exists a ring homomorphism $f: K\to R$ such that $gk:=gf(k)=f(k)$ for all $g\in G,k\in K$, i.e. $f(k)\in R^G$ for all $k\in K$.
2. Since it is of finite type, there exist $r_1,\dots,r_n\in R$ such that every element of $R$ can be written as a polynomial in $r_1,\dots,r_n$ with coeficients in $f(K)$.

Clearly, the products $r_1^{a_1}r_2^{a_2}...r_n^{a_n}$ generate $R$ as $R^G$-module, where $a_1,...,a_n$ are nonnegative integers. But, how can we conclude that $R$ is finitely generated as $R^G$-module? Thanks!

Comment: Since $R$ is a finitely generated as a $K$-algebra, then it is also finitely generated as an $R^G$-algebra. You already noted that $R$ is integral over $R^G$, so now you can apply integral + finite type $\iff$ finite as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835729/finite-type-integral-finite) or Lemma 10.35.5 of [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GH).